# Turning comma-separated lines of text in .txt file into lists in R

Tags: r, text

I'm loading a text file in R, and each line is supposed to be a list.

Originally, each line in the text file looked like:

```
list("a", "b", "c")
list("d", "e", "f")
```

and so on. Then after loading the text file in R, for each line of text, one could run

`eval(parse(text=noquote(line)))`

and R would read each line as a list of three elements. However, suppose instead that the lines in the text file are

```
"a", "b", "c"
"d", "e", "f"
```

How would one turn each line into a list of three elements? I've tried

`list(eval(parse(text=noquote(line))))`

but that doesn't work, since `parse` is meant to read the line of text as R code. I've also tried

`list(line)`

but that doesn't work either - it doesn't produce a list of three elements. So I'm kind of stuck, even though this seems pretty easy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use `?read.csv` then `split` the lines up? Running `eval(parse(...` for every line seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: I never thought about reading it as a csv, but doing this worked extremely well and was probably more efficient in the first place. Thanks!